# Command line arguments

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I've created a class called `Human` that works properly, it takes 2 arguments, age and name, to create a human.

To create a Human with command line arguments, I want to write

> java Filename -H "Anna" 25

And it should create a Human with `thatname="Anna"`, and `thatage=25`, where 25 is an int.

The code I've written is creating a list called Argument, and iterating through it to find `-H`. I need to do this because I'm going to be using this to create different classes later. I just need help with the syntax on the lines where I've written `thename=`, and `theage=`, because I don't know how to get the `next item in list`, and `next-next item in list`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> Argument = new ArrayList<String>();       

    for (String item: args) {
        Argument.add(item);         
    }

    for (String item2: Argument) {
        if (item2 == "-H") {
            thatname = Argument.get(item2+1)
            thatage = Argument.get(item2+2)
            Human person = new Human(thatname,thatage);
            System.out.println(person);
        }
```

Comment: [How do I compare Strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)
Also, what should the result of the addition of String and integer be? An index? How?

Comment: What do you mean? Where am I adding a string with an integer?

The part where I've written `Argument.get(item2+1)`, is not me trying to add an integer and a string, I know this is incorrect coding. I'm just trying to explain in the code that I'm trying to find the value that's after `item2`. I don't know the syntax for that. 

Also, I know that `get` doesn't work for me, because `get` only works for `ints`. So really what I'm asking for, is the syntax to `get` the `String` in `Argument`that's after item2 for `thatname`, and the one that's after that for `thatage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just loop the args?

```
for ( int i = 0; i < args.length; i++ ) }
    if (args[i].equals("-H")) {
       i++;
       thatName = args[i];
       i++;
       thatAge = args[i];
    }
}
```

You should add some code to catch if one does not follow the rules you have set. Probably not enough arguments or other things humans do at the keyboard...

Comment: I tried using this, but I just get an empty output. 

  `for ( int i = 0; i < args.length; i++ ) {
   if (args[i].equals("-H")) {
    i++;
    String thatName = args[i];
    i++;
    int thatAge = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
    
    Human person = new Human(thatAge,thatName);
    System.out.println(person);
   }
  }`

Comment: I think, person is not printable. Try to implement a toString() method.
public String toString() {
return getName() + " " + Integer.toString(getAge());
}

Answer (score 1):

```
thatname = Argument.get(Argument.indexOf(item2)+1);
thatage = Argument.get(Argument.indexOf(item2)+2);
```

OR you know that 1st element is  `-H`, 2nd element is `name` and 3rd is `age`, so you can use below code directly

```
thatname = Argument.get(1);
thatage = Integer.parseInt(Argument.get(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code have some problems, let me explain them to you for your assistance.

1. You cannot compare Strings with == you have to use **equals** method
   in the String to compare between two Strings.
2. You have to use this for loop **for(int i = 0; i < Argument.size();
   i++)** syntax so that you can iterate from zero to the number of
   items in the list.
3. **get** method in ArrayList take the index as parameter and return the value at that index.
4. You can add **i += 2** to skip the next two iterations which will
   return the name and age value of the human. (It is optional)

**Here is the working code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
ArrayList<String> Argument = new ArrayList<String>();       

for (String item: args) {
    Argument.add(item);         
}

String currentItem; 
for (int i = 0; i < Argument.size(); i++) { // it will iterate through all items

    currentItem = Argument.get(i); // getting the value with index;

    if (currentItem.equals("-H")) {

        String thatname = Argument.get(i+1);
        String thatage = Argument.get(i+2);

        i += 2; // Skipping 2 iterations of for loop which have name and age human.

        Human person = new Human(thatname,thatage);
        System.out.println(person);

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why using array list when you can directly use args? and while you're having only two parameters don't use a for loop access them direclty.
One thing you should know is that String is an object in java so comparing two Strings with `==` sign will return false even if they have same value (== will compare the id of the object), you should use `.equale()` function to compare the value of the object.

Check out this code :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length>0)
        {
                try{
                   if (args[0].equals("-H")) {
                    Human person = new Human( args[1],args[2]);
                    System.out.println(person);
                 }
                 }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
                     System.out.println("error with parameters");
                 }
         }else
           System.out.println("No command");
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot iterate the list using `String`. When iterating a list you required a index number like `list.get(indexNumber);`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> Argument = new ArrayList<String>();       

    for (String item: args) {
        Argument.add(item);         
    }

    for (int i=0;i<args.length;i++) {
        if (args[i].trim().equals("-H")) {
            i++;
            thatname = Argument.get(i);
            i++;
            thatage = Argument.get(i);
            Human person = new Human(thatname,thatage);
            System.out.println(person.getName()+"  "+person.getAge());
        }
```